# Swift CoreData - objects not being inserted in to managed object context

Tags: swift, core-data, nsurlrequest, combine

I've reworked this question after further research and in response to comments that it was too long.

I am downloading and decoding data, in CSV format using CodableCSV, from three URLs and I've been able to confirm that I am receiving all the data I expect (as of today, 35027 lines). As the data is decoded, I am injecting a NSManagedObjectContext in to the decoded object. Here is my managed object class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(MacListEntry)
class MacListEntry: NSManagedObject, Decodable {

  //var id = UUID()
  @NSManaged var registry: String?
  @NSManaged var assignment: String?
  @NSManaged var org_name: String?
  @NSManaged var org_addr: String?

  required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

    guard let keyManObjContext = CodingUserInfoKey.managedObjectContext,
      let context = decoder.userInfo[keyManObjContext] as? NSManagedObjectContext,
      let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "MacListEntry", in: context) else {
        fatalError("Failed to receive managed object context")
    }

    self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)

    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.registry = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .registry)
    self.assignment = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .assignment)
    self.org_name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .org_name)
    self.org_addr = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .org_addr)
  }

  private enum CodingKeys: Int, CodingKey {
    case registry = 0
    case assignment = 1
    case org_name = 2
    case org_addr = 3
  }
}

public extension CodingUserInfoKey {
  static let managedObjectContext = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "managedObjectContext")
}
```

I then attempt to save the context using `try context.save()` but before doing so, examine the numbers of records I am trying to insert using:

```
print("Deleted objects: (self.persistentContainer.viewContext.deletedObjects.count)")
print("Inserted objects: (self.persistentContainer.viewContext.insertedObjects.count)")
print("Has changes: \(self.persistentContainer.viewContext.hasChanges)")
```

and get a different number of inserted records every time the code runs - always short, by around 0.5%. I am struggling to understand under what circumstances objects added to a managed object context in this way simply don't appear in the list of inserted objects and don't make it in to the saved database. Is there a practical limit on the number of records inserted in one go?

Can anyone suggest where else I should be looking - the error is tiny enough that it looks like the program is running fine, but it isn't.

Many thanks.

Comment: When asking for debug help, the idea is that you provide a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to zero in on the issue. More often than not, you either expose a gap in your understanding, or you find a bug. I doubt you'd get anyone to parse through all this of code.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the problem and if I'm correct, posting my solution here may help others. I'm downloading the three CSV files using Combine and dataTaskPublisher - creating three separate publishers and then merging them in to a single stream. While I was aware that I couldn't update the UI on a background thread so had added the .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main) in the chain (indicated by (1) in the code below), I put it AFTER the .tryMap { } where the decoding was happening. Because it was the process of decoding that inserted the object in to the managed object context, this must have been happening asynchronously and hence causing problems. By moving the .receive(on: ...) line ABOVE the .tryMap (see (2) below), this appears to have resolved the problem - or at least made the fetch, decode and insert return the correct number of inserted records consistently.

```
enum RequestError: Error {
    case sessionError(error: HTTPURLResponse)
}


struct Agent {

  let decoder: CSVDecoder

  struct Response<T> {
    let value: T
    let response: URLResponse
  }
  func run<T: Decodable>(_ request: URLRequest) -> AnyPublisher<Response<T>, Error> {
    print("In run()")
    return URLSession.shared
      .dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
      .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)    // -- (1)
      .tryMap { result -> Response<T> in
        print(result)

        guard let httpResponse = result.response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
          throw RequestError.sessionError(error: result.response as! HTTPURLResponse)
        }
        let value = try self.decoder.decode(T.self, from: result.data)
        return Response(value: value, response: result.response)
    }
    //.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main).    // -- (2)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}

struct Endpoint {
  var agent: Agent
  let base: String
}

extension Endpoint {

  func run<T: Decodable>(_ request: URLRequest) -> AnyPublisher<T, Error> {
    return agent.run(request)
      .map(\.value)
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }

  func fetch(thing: String) -> AnyPublisher<[MacListEntry], Error> {
    return run(URLRequest(url: URL(string: base+thing)!))
  }

}

struct Response: Codable {
  let name: String
}

--- snip ---

    var requests:[AnyPublisher<[MacListEntry],Error>] = []
    requests.append(endpoint.fetch(thing: "file1.csv"))
    requests.append(endpoint.fetch(thing: "file2.csv"))
    requests.append(endpoint.fetch(thing: "file3.csv"))


    let _ = Publishers.MergeMany(requests)
      .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        ...
      )
      .store(in: &bag)
```